# How to get ANTLR4 grammar to parse over a single line without requiring line break in the middle?

Tags: antlr4, dsl

I'm currently relearning ANTLR and I'm having a bit of an issue with my grammar and parsing is. I'm editing it in IntelliJ IDEA with the ANTLR plugin and I'm using ANTLR version 4.9.2.

My grammar is as follows

```
grammar Pattern;
pattern:
    patternName
    patternMeaning
    patternMoves;

patternName     :   'Name:'     NAME            ;
patternMeaning  :   'Meaning:'  NAME            ;

patternMoves    :   'Moves:'    (patternStep)+  ;
patternStep     :   'Turn' angle stance;
stance          :   'Walking Stance';
angle   :   ('90'|'180'|'270'|'360') '°' 'anti-'? 'clockwise';

NAME    :   WORD (' ' WORD)*;
fragment WORD    :   [a-zA-Z]+;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

now when I try and parse the following text, I get the following error `line 2:9 mismatched input 'clockwise Walking Stance' expecting {'anti-', 'clockwise'}`

```
Name: Il Jang
Meaning: Heaven and light
Moves:
Turn 90° clockwise Walking Stance
```

However, if I change the text to the below it works without any issues. How can I tweak my grammar to allow me to parse it on one line?

```
Name: Il Jang
Meaning: Heaven and light
Moves:
Turn 90° clockwise 
Walking Stance
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] including your lexer rules. If I add a single rule `WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;`, both of your inputs work fine. If I don't add that rule, I get errors about unexpected white space for both inputs. Either way I can't reproduce the error you're getting.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's a good idea to add `EOF` to your start rule. Otherwise superfluous input at the end will be ignored instead of causing a syntax error.

Comment: I've updated my example to be my whole grammar, I'd tried to remove the bit's that weren't relevant however that broke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `clockwise Walking Stance` is a valid `NAME`, so it's interpreted as such rather than as an instance of the `clockwise` keyword followed by the `NAME` `Walking Stance`. Adding a line break fixes this because line breaks can't appear in names.

To fix this, you should turn `WORD` into a lexer rule and `NAME` into a parser rule. That way the `name` rule will only be tried in places where the parser actually expects a name, so it won't try to interpret `clockwise` as part of a name. And the `WORD` rule won't eat keywords because the match produced by the `WORD` rule won't be longer than the keyword, so the keyword wins.

Comment: That's brill thanks, I've changed them to `WORD:[a-zA-Z]+;` and `name:(WORD)+;` and that seems to have resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

If this is your entire grammar, then there are no lexer rules defining the handling of whaitespace.  In fact, the are no explicit lexer rules. (ANTLR will create implicit lexer rules for any literal strings in your parser rules (unless the match an already define grammar rule.))

Your grammar is essentially (in ANTLR’s perception)

```
grammar Pattern;

patternMoves    :   T_1    (patternStep)+  ;

patternStep     :   T_2 angle stance;

stance          :  T_3;

angle   :   (T_4|T_5|T_6|T_7) T_8 T_9? T_10;

T_1: ‘Moves:’;
T_2: ‘Turn’;
T_3: 'Walking Stance';
T_4: '90';
T_5: '180';
T_6: '270';
T_7: '360';
T_8: '°';
T_9: 'anti-';
T_10: 'clockwise';
```

ANTLR’s processing takes a stream of characters, passes them to a lexer, which must decide what to do with all characters (even whitespace).  The lexer produces a stream of tokens that the parser rules process.

You need some lexer rule that prescribes how to handle whatespace:

```
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Is a common way of handling this.  It tokenized all whitespace as a `WS` token, but then `skip`s handing that token to the parser.  (This is very handy as you won’t have to sprinkle `WS` or `WS?` items all through your grammar where whitespace is expected.

That your plugin accepts you input would imply to me that it ***may*** be treating each line of input as a new parse.